# Versioning - possible to remove overwrite possibility when checking in a file?

Tags: sharepoint-online, versioning

I want to know if it is possible to remove this option from checking in files?

[image: check in options]

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, there is no way to remove this option from checking in files.

===================================

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Comment: I’m checking how the things are going on about this issue. Whether the answer helps you? If there is any problem with this issue, feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I've only seen that additional Check in option when in a **Site Pages** library.  In these library types if **Minor and Major** versions are tracked then the option cannot be disabled. (Libraries based on the Document library template do not have the overwrite draft option.) Do you know if the library is a repurposed **Site Pages** library, meaning had its name - and possibly its URL - changed?  If any of the following are true, you know the library is repurposed:  Library's URL contains **/sitepages**, available content types include web pages, and if there is a view titled **By - Author**.

If the library is a **Site Pages** library and you don't want the **Overwrite current minor version** to appear you can:  **1)** Change the version settings to only track major versions. (*No drafts are maintained*.) **2)** Create a new library based on the Document library template, first configure it to use the same custom columns like **External link** and **DocNum**, and then use the [Move to](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/move-or-copy-files-in-sharepoint-00e2f483-4df3-46be-a861-1f5f0c1a87bc) feature to moves the files to the new library.

[image]